# Solution to Dirichlet problem and Brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

In the above context, given a Brownian motion B started from a point $x$ in a bounded domain $D$,  my notes define the solution to the Dirichlet problem with boundary value $f$ on $\partial D$ to be the function

$$ S(x) = E_x(f(B_T))$$

where $T$ is the exit time of $B$ from $D$. $E_x$ is supposed to indicate the expectation w.r.t. the probability measure under which $B$ started from $x$ is a Brownian motion, but how can I make sense of this? The definition of $P_x$ seems so indirect to me that I cannot fathom this probability measure, nor be confident that I understand correctly. Can somebody clarify the situation in the most direct manner possible?

Comment: Are you trying to carefully expand definitions layer by layer or are you just trying to get the main intuition? For the latter: the expression $E_x[f(B_T)]$ asks you to run a Brownian motion started at the point $x$ until time $T$, then evaluate $f$ at the point where you stopped. Then you average the results you get by doing that over different paths of the BM. Note that you'll always stop on the boundary, so the expression is well defined even if $f$ is only defined on the boundary (assuming $f$ is not too singular).

Comment: If somehow what is throwing you off is really $P_x$ and $E_x$ and $P$ and $E$ are OK for BM, you can remove that issue by looking at $E[f(x+B_{T_x})]$. Note that now I moved the $x$ onto $T$, and there's no way around that.

Comment: First of all, thanks for taking the time. As for the issue: ascribing the dependence from $x$ to the exit time is already more intuitive, for sure. Still, the notes seem to suggest that for each point $x$ there is a probability measure under which $B$ started from $x$ is a BM. This is puzzling to me from a formal standpoint (why does it exist) and raises other questions, like: one probability measure per point? Are they all different? How do we construct them?

Comment: In principle they're different, but it's easy enough to construct them, as they are all just translations of the probability measure $P_0$, i.e. $P_x(A)=P_0(A-x)$.

Comment: Is the story always so simple? Can you mention a book where this is clearly explained? Thanks again

Comment: Sadly I mostly learned probability from professors, not really books. *Probability with Martingales* by Williams is a good book, though.

Comment: Would something like this be in that book?

Comment: I took a quick look again and it looks like no, sadly the only other books I've used are Shiryaev (which I don't think goes into this either) and Freidlin/Wentzell *Random perturbations of dynamical systems* (which uses it, but takes it for granted basically).

Comment: From what I see below, your doubt seems to be on BM's construction itself : so it's far more basic than what I see here.

Comment: Let's see : Schilling and Partzsch , Brownian motion for starters is an excellent book that explains everything you need. The story is already well captured in the comments above, but the reason why we require $\mathbb P_x$ for each $x$ is for the more general notion of a Brownian or Markovian "family". Over there, it's important as to how the starting measure should look like. The between the Brownian motion and normal random variables is expressed by the fact that increments are normally distributed. So yes : "one measure per point!"

Comment: Will definitely take a look tomorrow, thanks a lot @TeresaLisbon

Comment: @Dalamar It's tomorrow for me! When it's tomorrow for you let me know. I hope that you are eventually able to get the concepts right : they are arbitrary at times, but occasionally they have higher interests at heart. We may also need discussion leading to an affirmative answer, so perhaps I may not outright answer your question, but we can seep through the doubts slowly.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is just about the definition of Brownian Motion as a probability measure.

Let's work in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and fix some $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ (you can pretend it's the origin). Let $\Gamma_x = \{\gamma : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^2 \hspace{1mm} | \hspace{1.5mm} \gamma \text{ is continuous and has } \gamma(0)=x\}$. We define a probability measure $\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{P}_x$ on $\Gamma_x$; the sigma-algebra is the Borel one.

Let $E$ be a Borel subset of $\Gamma_x$. We now define $\mathbb{P}(E)$. We will use some external source of randomness (this hopefully is fine with you). For each $n \ge 1$, let $\gamma_n : \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the random function defined by $\gamma_n(0) = x$, and for $t \ge 1$, $\gamma_n(t+1) := \gamma_n(t)+\sigma_t$, where $\sigma_t$ is chosen uniformly at random from $\{(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1),(0,1)\}$. Extend $\gamma_n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{\ge 0}$ by defining $\gamma_n(t+\delta) := \gamma_n(t)+\delta(\gamma_n(t+1)-\gamma_n(t))$ for $t \in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0}$ and $\delta \in [0,1)$. Then each $\gamma_n$ is continuous with $\gamma_n(0) = x$. Therefore, $\gamma := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\gamma_n}{2^n}$ is a continuous function with $\gamma(0) = x$. We define $\mathbb{P}(E)$ to be the probability that $\gamma \in E$.

The point is that if you choose an element $\gamma \in \Gamma_x$ randomly according to $\mathbb{P}$, what you get corresponds to your intuition of what Brownian Motion starting at $x$ is; namely, a "random walk" starting at $x$.

Comment: I upvoted your answer and I thank you for your time, but I can't accept it because I feel it didn't significantly improve my understanding of the situation. Most texts simply start introducing this probability without defining it and I can't believe something like this is just swept under the rug or taken for granted, there must be a general construction of this thing.

Comment: @Dalamar What kind of answer are you looking for? I very clearly defined the probability. I think you should reread the answer.

Comment: I'll try to tell you my doubts, that perhaps start even before you think. Why do we even need a different probability measure for each point at which the BM starts? When one defines BM, one makes sure the trajectories are almost surely continuous - so there is a probability measure already. What is it that changes if we start from an arbitrary point instead of $0$? Or better yet, how does this all fit in the definition of BM as a sum of independent centered gaussian random variables?